# Amend missing times to datetime series in R

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I have an hourly time series of datetimes formatted as "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" and as class "character". The goal is to convert character data to date and time using as.POSIXct. However, some records in the time series are missing the time portion ("%H:%M:%S"), although the number of records per date (24) is correct.

Is it possible to fill in the time portion of these records with a sequence of hours starting with 00:00:00 and ending with 23:00:00 for each date?

**Original Dataset:**

```
Date_time 
...
1991-03-31 21:00:00
1991-03-31 22:00:00 
1991-03-31 23:00:00
1991-04-01
1991-04-01
1991-04-01
...
```

**What I want:**

```
Date_time 
...
1991-03-31 21:00:00
1991-03-31 22:00:00 
1991-03-31 23:00:00
1991-04-01 00:00:00
1991-04-01 01:00:00
1991-04-01 02:00:00
...
```

The closest I've gotten is a workaround while still in character format, but the result starts at hour 16:00:00. Plz send halp.

```
hours=c("00:00:00", "01:00:00", "02:00:00", "03:00:00", "04:00:00", "05:00:00", "06:00:00", "07:00:00", "08:00:00", "09:00:00", "10:00:00", "11:00:00", "12:00:00","13:00:00", "14:00:00", "15:00:00", "16:00:00", "17:00:00", "18:00:00", "19:00:00", "20:00:00","21:00:00", "22:00:00", "23:00:00")

Dataset %>%
  mutate(Date_time_filled = ifelse(nchar(as.character(Date_time))<19, 
                                   paste(Date_time, hours), 
                                   paste(Date_time)))
```

**What I got (wrong):**

```
Date_time 
...
1991-03-31 21:00:00
1991-03-31 22:00:00 
1991-03-31 23:00:00
1991-04-01 16:00:00
1991-04-01 17:00:00
1991-04-01 18:00:00
...
```

**EDIT:**

```
 X metadata.id metadata.name metadata.lat metadata.lon              Date_time data.v data.s data.f
1   1     9411340 Santa Barbara      34.4031    -119.6928 1990-10-22 01:00:00     NA     NA    1,1
2   2     9411340 Santa Barbara      34.4031    -119.6928 1990-10-22 02:00:00     NA     NA    1,1
3   3     9411340 Santa Barbara      34.4031    -119.6928 1990-10-22 03:00:00     NA     NA    1,1
4   4     9411340 Santa Barbara      34.4031    -119.6928 1990-10-22 04:00:00     NA     NA    1,1
5   5     9411340 Santa Barbara      34.4031    -119.6928 1990-10-22 05:00:00     NA     NA    1,1
6   6     9411340 Santa Barbara      34.4031    -119.6928 1990-10-22 06:00:00     NA     NA    1,1
7   7     9411340 Santa Barbara      34.4031    -119.6928 1990-10-22 07:00:00     NA     NA    1,1
8   8     9411340 Santa Barbara      34.4031    -119.6928 1990-10-22 08:00:00     NA     NA    1,1
9   9     9411340 Santa Barbara      34.4031    -119.6928 1990-10-22 09:00:00     NA     NA    1,1
10 10     9411340 Santa Barbara      34.4031    -119.6928 1990-10-22 10:00:00     NA     NA    1,1
11 11     9411340 Santa Barbara      34.4031    -119.6928 1990-10-22 11:00:00     NA     NA    1,1
12 12     9411340 Santa Barbara      34.4031    -119.6928 1990-10-22 12:00:00     NA     NA    1,1
13 13     9411340 Santa Barbara      34.4031    -119.6928 1990-10-22 13:00:00     NA     NA    1,1
14 14     9411340 Santa Barbara      34.4031    -119.6928 1990-10-22 14:00:00     NA     NA    1,1
15 15     9411340 Santa Barbara      34.4031    -119.6928 1990-10-22 15:00:00     NA     NA    1,1
16 16     9411340 Santa Barbara      34.4031    -119.6928 1990-10-22 16:00:00     NA     NA    1,1
17 17     9411340 Santa Barbara      34.4031    -119.6928 1990-10-22 17:00:00     NA     NA    1,1
18 18     9411340 Santa Barbara      34.4031    -119.6928 1990-10-22 18:00:00     NA     NA    1,1
19 19     9411340 Santa Barbara      34.4031    -119.6928 1990-10-22 19:00:00     NA     NA    1,1
20 20     9411340 Santa Barbara      34.4031    -119.6928 1990-10-22 20:00:00     NA     NA    1,1
21 21     9411340 Santa Barbara      34.4031    -119.6928 1990-10-22 21:00:00     NA     NA    1,1
22 22     9411340 Santa Barbara      34.4031    -119.6928 1990-10-22 22:00:00     NA     NA    1,1
23 23     9411340 Santa Barbara      34.4031    -119.6928 1990-10-22 23:00:00     NA     NA    1,1
24 24     9411340 Santa Barbara      34.4031    -119.6928 1990-10-23 00:00:00     NA     NA    1,1
25 25     9411340 Santa Barbara      34.4031    -119.6928 1990-10-23 01:00:00     NA     NA    1,1
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, or it at least it can put you on track:

```
# This is the working horse:
seq(as.POSIXct("1991-03-31 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("1991-04-02 23:00:00"), by = "1 hour")

 [1] "1991-03-31 00:00:00 -05" "1991-03-31 01:00:00 -05" "1991-03-31 02:00:00 -05" "1991-03-31 03:00:00 -05" "1991-03-31 04:00:00 -05"
 [6] "1991-03-31 05:00:00 -05" "1991-03-31 06:00:00 -05" "1991-03-31 07:00:00 -05" "1991-03-31 08:00:00 -05" "1991-03-31 09:00:00 -05"
[11] "1991-03-31 10:00:00 -05" "1991-03-31 11:00:00 -05" "1991-03-31 12:00:00 -05" "1991-03-31 13:00:00 -05" "1991-03-31 14:00:00 -05"
[16] "1991-03-31 15:00:00 -05" "1991-03-31 16:00:00 -05" "1991-03-31 17:00:00 -05" "1991-03-31 18:00:00 -05" "1991-03-31 19:00:00 -05"
[21] "1991-03-31 20:00:00 -05" "1991-03-31 21:00:00 -05" "1991-03-31 22:00:00 -05" "1991-03-31 23:00:00 -05" "1991-04-01 00:00:00 -05"
[26] "1991-04-01 01:00:00 -05" "1991-04-01 02:00:00 -05" "1991-04-01 03:00:00 -05" "1991-04-01 04:00:00 -05" "1991-04-01 05:00:00 -05"
[31] "1991-04-01 06:00:00 -05" "1991-04-01 07:00:00 -05" "1991-04-01 08:00:00 -05" "1991-04-01 09:00:00 -05" "1991-04-01 10:00:00 -05"
[36] "1991-04-01 11:00:00 -05" "1991-04-01 12:00:00 -05" "1991-04-01 13:00:00 -05" "1991-04-01 14:00:00 -05" "1991-04-01 15:00:00 -05"
[41] "1991-04-01 16:00:00 -05" "1991-04-01 17:00:00 -05" "1991-04-01 18:00:00 -05" "1991-04-01 19:00:00 -05" "1991-04-01 20:00:00 -05"
[46] "1991-04-01 21:00:00 -05" "1991-04-01 22:00:00 -05" "1991-04-01 23:00:00 -05" "1991-04-02 00:00:00 -05" "1991-04-02 01:00:00 -05"
[51] "1991-04-02 02:00:00 -05" "1991-04-02 03:00:00 -05" "1991-04-02 04:00:00 -05" "1991-04-02 05:00:00 -05" "1991-04-02 06:00:00 -05"
[56] "1991-04-02 07:00:00 -05" "1991-04-02 08:00:00 -05" "1991-04-02 09:00:00 -05" "1991-04-02 10:00:00 -05" "1991-04-02 11:00:00 -05"
[61] "1991-04-02 12:00:00 -05" "1991-04-02 13:00:00 -05" "1991-04-02 14:00:00 -05" "1991-04-02 15:00:00 -05" "1991-04-02 16:00:00 -05"
[66] "1991-04-02 17:00:00 -05" "1991-04-02 18:00:00 -05" "1991-04-02 19:00:00 -05" "1991-04-02 20:00:00 -05" "1991-04-02 21:00:00 -05"
[71] "1991-04-02 22:00:00 -05" "1991-04-02 23:00:00 -05"
```

It could be used like this:

```
Dataset$date_time_filled <- seq(as.POSIXct(Dataset$date_time[1]),
                                as.POSIXct(Dataset$date_time[nrow(Dataset)]), 
                                by = "1 hour")
```

In case the last reading of `date_time` is missing the time, it will work, but will consider the last one as if it occurred at 00:00:00, so it may error because of differing vector lengths. That you'll likely have to adjust manually.

Comment: Thanks for this @PavoDive. I think I did have some differing vector lengths complicating things. See my answer below. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As you already have number of records present for each Date and only the time portion is missing one approach is to use `sprintf` and replicate the time part for each Date.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date_time1 = as.POSIXct(Date_time), 
         Date_time1 = paste(Date_time1, sprintf("%02d:00:00", 0:23)))
```

Trying this for hours 0 to 5 on small subset.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Date_time1 = as.POSIXct(Date_time), 
         Date_time1 = paste(Date_time1, sprintf("%02d:00:00", 0:5)))


#             Date_time          Date_time1
#1  1991-03-31 00:00:00 1991-03-31 00:00:00
#2  1991-03-31 01:00:00 1991-03-31 01:00:00
#3  1991-03-31 02:00:00 1991-03-31 02:00:00
#4  1991-03-31 03:00:00 1991-03-31 03:00:00
#5  1991-03-31 04:00:00 1991-03-31 04:00:00
#6  1991-03-31 05:00:00 1991-03-31 05:00:00
#7           1991-04-01 1991-04-01 00:00:00
#8           1991-04-01 1991-04-01 01:00:00
#9           1991-04-01 1991-04-01 02:00:00
#10          1991-04-01 1991-04-01 03:00:00
#11          1991-04-01 1991-04-01 04:00:00
#12          1991-04-01 1991-04-01 05:00:00
```

You can run `as.POSIXct` on `Date_time1` column to convert it into `POSIXct` object.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date_time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("1991-03-31 00:00:00", "1991-03-31 01:00:00", 
"1991-03-31 02:00:00", "1991-03-31 03:00:00", "1991-03-31 04:00:00", 
"1991-03-31 05:00:00", "1991-04-01"), class = "factor")), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot, but for some reason, the first filled in time still starts at 16:00:00 not 00:00:00 when I try to apply to my data. However, your example data works great.

Comment: @dough Can you update your post with first few lines of your data just as I did using `dput` ? Do `dput(head(df, 25))` and copy/paste the output in your post.

Comment: It likely results in 16:00 instead of 00:00 because of the time zone you're in. Use the `tz =` argument in the call to `as.POSIXct`. See its help page too

Comment: @RonakShah I added first few lines from my real data.

Comment: @PavoDive no including the time zone did not help. I used Date_time=as.POSIXct((Date_time), origin="1970-01-01", tz="America/Los_Angeles", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"). However, I did want to avoid putting the data into date-time format just yet, because it seems to complicate things

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the missing times into the full time series dataset, I ended up having to go back to the individual datasets containing only one month of data. Months missing data were always April, hence 30 days. Then the following worked:

```
#Fix April Datasets missing hour data
hours=c("00:00:00", "01:00:00", "02:00:00", "03:00:00", "04:00:00", "05:00:00", "06:00:00", "07:00:00", "08:00:00", "09:00:00", "10:00:00", "11:00:00", "12:00:00","13:00:00", "14:00:00", "15:00:00", "16:00:00", "17:00:00", "18:00:00", "19:00:00", "20:00:00","21:00:00", "22:00:00", "23:00:00")
pattern=glob2rx("******04**.csv")

#Monthly Dataset
MonthlyData_filenames=list.files(path="~/.../Hourly",
                        pattern=pattern, full.names = T)
for(i in 1:length(MonthlyData_filenames)){
  input = read.csv(MonthlyData_filenames[i], head=TRUE, sep=",")
  if(nchar(as.character(input$Date_time))>=19){
    next
  }
  output = input %>%
    mutate(hour = rep(hours, times=30)) %>%
    mutate(Date_time = paste(Date_time, hour, sep=" ")) %>%
    select(-hour)
  write.csv(output, MonthlyData_filenames[i], row.names=FALSE)
}
```